# Unexpected Servlet caching

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a Tomcat7 web App consisting of an HTML file with form, as well as a Servlet and a Java bean. The HTML form calls the Servlet, which takes the request parameters, does some preparations, creates an instance of the bean and calls it's String doSearch(String arg1, int arg2) method. Each time the Servlet is called, it sets the bean to null and creates a new Instance.

The problem is that in each session the former results (created by the bean) stay visible (which should not appear). I don't use any static variables or classes.

When I run the code as Java Program it works as expected. The only way to get rid of the old results for now is restarting Tomcat

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code for my servlet:

```
public class LingoServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LingoServlet() {
    super();
}

String HTML_HEAD = "" + "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"" + "-//W3C//DTD HTML " + "4.01 Transitional//EN\" "
        + "\"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">" + "<html>" + "<head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" "
        + "type=\"text/css\" href=\"default.css\">" + "<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"max-age=0\" />"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\" />"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"0\" />"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT\" />"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"pragma\" content=\"no-cache\" />" + "<title>Lingo Helper</title>"
        + "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" " + "content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">" + "</head>" + "<body>";
String BODY = "<h1>Results:</h1>";
String FOOTER = "</html>";

// Prevent caching by destroying it first.
LingoSearcher ls = null;

HttpServletRequest req = null;
HttpServletResponse res = null;
PrintWriter pw = null;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // PrintWriter pw = null;
    LingoSearcher ls = null;
    PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();

    String wl = req.getParameter("wl").trim();
    String wc = req.getParameter("wc").trim().toLowerCase();

    int wlength = Integer.parseInt(wl);

    LingoSearcher searcher = new LingoSearcher();

    try {
        BODY = BODY + "<div id=\"scroll\">" + "<pre>" + ls.doSearch(wc, wlength) + "</pre></div>";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "An error occured. Please check your input" + " parameters and try again.<br/>"
                + "If the prblem persists please report the error" + "as 122";
        pw.println(msg);
    }
    pw.print(HTML_HEAD);
    pw.print(BODY);
    pw.print(FOOTER);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    res = null;
    req = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the code of Servlet and HTML form ?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't fit. Can you send me your Email?

Comment: I will share the complete code as a zip to Google Drive and post the link here.

Comment: The .war file is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5P_61PgIb6gc0VfRC1sbzdhUjQ Thanks

Comment: Please note the code in the.war is optimized for Tomcat 7

Comment: Your code definitely fits. I'm adding it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually looks okay (though it has a lot of architectural problems and potential NPEs, etc.), except for this part:

```java
// Prevent caching by destroying it first.
LingoSearcher ls = null;

HttpServletRequest req = null;
HttpServletResponse res = null;
PrintWriter pw = null;
```

Something tells me you have changed the code before posting it, because those class-level members are *never* used. You have *shadowed* them all in your `doGet` method, so the local names take precedence.If you had *not* shadowed them – that is, if you had used the class-level members then you would have been retaining references to objects (especially the request and response objects) longer than they should live.

In web applications, servlets are (usually) created a single time and live for the life of the application (until it is undeployed). Your servlets should be completely free of class-level members unless they are properly thread-safe.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a Servlet use a JSP and declare a bean with scope of "page" That solved my problem. Avoid the use of Servlets anyway. JSP's are much easier and have many options.

Comment: -1 for recommending the use of JSP over Servlets. Read about [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).